# Refactoring to apply method for every getter

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I have a class which describes some object. It contains many parameters and therefore a lot of getters and setters. I wish to know if there is refactoring tool which will allow me to apply a method for every getter in my class.
E.g

```
public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
```

Method

```
private String zerochecker(String var) {
        String bufvar = "";

        if (var == null || var.trim().length() <= 0
                || var.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                || var.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
        } else {
            bufvar = var;
        }
        return bufvar;
    }
```

Result:

```
public String getStatus() {
        return zerochecker(status);
    }
```

Comment: off-topic: you could skip the var.equalsIgnoreCase("null") check because the var.trim().etc. check will catch this case as well.

Comment: off-topic too: var.trim().length() < 0 will never happen, you can directly test var.trim().length() == 0.

Comment: By the way, why not assign directly bufvar to var and set bufvar = "" if your condition is true, that way you can drop the else instead of doing nothing if the condition is true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way i found it possible to do - is to change template of automatic generation of getters. Solution is vagues, but can be used.

Answer (score 2):

No, there cannot be a tool for such a refactoring, as that is not a refactoring. A refactoring (as available for instance in the Eclipse refactoring menus) does not change the behaviour, only the structure of the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no such a tool. You maybe need to do it by hands. You could use [AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html) but is it worth it?

Answer (score 0):

That would appear easy:

1. Let eclipse generate the getters
2. Use a search and replace with regular expressions: "return (.*);" by "return zerochecker(\1);"

You may need to fix the syntax of the expressions.